# Question about coherent population trapping

Tags: laser, atoms, coherent-states

In coherent population trapping, if we denote the ground states in a $\Lambda$-like system as $|0\rangle$  and $|1 \rangle$ and the excited state $|2 \rangle$, there is a linear combination $|d \rangle = \sin\theta |1 \rangle + \cos\theta|0 \rangle$ for some $\theta$ which usually depends on the laser intensity, which is a dark state i.e. if the atom ends up there it won't interact with the laser field.

The other orthogonal combination $|b \rangle = \cos\theta |1 \rangle - \sin\theta|0 \rangle$ is the bright state, which is maximally coupled to the excited state.

When people talk about coherent population trapping, they say if you end up in $|d \rangle$ you can accumulate all your population there, if enough interaction time with the laser is allowed. But I am not sure I understand how the population ends up there. Usually I imagine that the atoms in the excited state decay to $|0 \rangle$ or $|1 \rangle$, not a linear combination of the two.

Does it mean that in this case, when I think of the laser-atom system, the atoms decay to either $|d \rangle$ or $|b \rangle$, instead of $|0 \rangle$ and $|1 \rangle$? And if so why is that the case? Thank you!